# Refresh token in php page via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, token

I'm using a token system to request php page via Ajax, the problem is that I cannot do more than one request via ajax from the same page because I cannot refresh the token in the initial page.

### More precisely:

I have php page where I have multiple buttons that recalls to different ajax function that loads different form or data inside the page from other pages without refreshing the page (of course with ajax), when I request a page, the request must have a valid token, if not, the page will be not loaded, when I request a page the first time, the initial token is not valid anymore so I cannot request other pages because the requests will be rejected because of the token.

Edit:
Main php page

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
$token = Token::generate();
?>
<button class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' id='1' onclick='edit(this.id)'>Edit</button>
<button class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' id='3' onclick='edit(this.id)'>Bookings</button>
<div id="edit">
</div>
function edit(id)
{
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#edit").load("ajax_edit.php", {id: id, token: '<?php echo $token ?>'});
});
}
```

ajax_edit.php

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

if(Input::exists('post'))
{
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token')))
    {

    } else
  {
    Redirect::to(404);
  }
}

?>
<form id="Form">
//various input fields
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo Input::get('id') ?>">
<button class='btn btn-default btn-sm' type='submit'>Edit</button>
</form>
<script>
var options = { 
    target:     '#Form', 
    url:        'ajax_edit.php',
    type:       'post', 
    success:    function() { 
        alert('Thanks for your edit!'); 
    } 
}; 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Form').ajaxForm(options); 
}); 
</script>
```

How can solve this problem?

Comment: please post some code that you have...

Comment: How does token system work? How are you accessing and sending token? Provide some code and more detailed explanation

Comment: @charlietfl I added some code

Comment: Side note: You don't need the `#` in the id attr, `<form id="Form">`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Token` class has a function such as `refresh` or `newToken`, you can add an extra parameter that tells it to return a new token for further requests (and require the current token to verify the request for another token is valid).

The HTML would be like this:

```
<form id="#Form">
<!-- various input fields -->
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo Input::get('id') ?>">

<!-- Here's the new parameter -->
<input type="hidden" name="getNewToken" value="true">
<button class='btn btn-default btn-sm' type='submit'>Edit</button>
</form>
```

Then have the ajax's server-side code be in its own page with no HTML code (so you can return a response of JSON).

```
<?php
$responseObject = array( "status" => "ok", "response" => array() );

if(Input::exists('post'))
{
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token')))
    {
        //They want a new token
        if ( isset( $_POST[ "getNewToken" ] ) && $_POST[ "getNewToken" ] == "true" )
        {
            //Add token for another request
            $responseObject[ "response" ][ "token" ] = Token::newToken();
        }
    } else
  {
    Redirect::to(404);
  }
}

//Now output the response
echo json_encode( $responseObject );
?>
```

Comment: So I have to create a new php page where to send the request?

Comment: And how will I change the token value in the initial page?

Comment: By using the DOM in the ajax callback. For example, if the token input is called `name="token"`, you would do `document.getElementById( "Form" ).elements[ "token" ].value = response.token;`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Don, I will try to implement it in this way! :)